# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am attempting to refactor some legacy code I wrote 2 years ago. A `gulpfile.js` file to be precise.

It seems like the problem is here:

```
// gulp.task('default', ['browserify', 'copy'], function() {
//   return gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['browserify', 'copy']);
// });
```

I commented it out and replaced it with this:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browserify', 'copy'), function() {
  return gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['browserify', 'copy']);
});
```

Not good enough. The whole file looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify'); // Converts jsx to js
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'); // Converts string to a stream

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  browserify('./src/js/main.js')
    .transform('reactify')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('copy', function() {
  gulp.src('src/index.html').pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
  gulp.src('src/css/*.*').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
  gulp.src('src/images/*.*').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
  gulp.src('src/js/vendors/*.*').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// gulp.task('default', ['browserify', 'copy'], function() {
//   return gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['browserify', 'copy']);
// });

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browserify', 'copy'), function() {
  return gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['browserify', 'copy']);
});
```

I have read through some of the getting started documentation, but what I have read thus far has not helped me refactor this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue faced me because of the version of gulp I installed using `npm i gulp`
to solve this quickly, downgrade to that gulp version you used before 2 years and everything will work fine.

Comment: Solution is to upgrade to gulp 4 and he decided to use my way as I think he has no time to read new gulp docs..like you are searching for quick solution for your issue dear....It is his quick solution and I did not use any scripts to say it is a workaround!....gulp 3 still working as we all knew like before ... anyway thanks for you precious comment

Answer (score 5):

With Gulp 4.0 the way you run tasks in  series has got changed. You can read and get what you want using below link 
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md.